# CSS @import is not working with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have a CSS file in which I am importing other CSS files using `@import`. When I compile that CSS file using laravel-mix, I am unable to import the included CSS files after compilation

I have following CSScss stored in 
`resources/css/icheck/all.css`

```css
/* iCheck plugin skins
----------------------------------- */
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
@import url("square/_all.css");
@import url("flat/_all.css");
@import url("line/_all.css");
@import url("polaris/polaris.css");
@import url("futurico/futurico.css");
```

And following is my `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .styles('resources/css/icheck/all.css', 'public/css/icheck.css')
```

Now when I run `'npm run dev'` command it should copy the imported CSS files, but I have only the following `icheck.css` file in `public/css` folder

```css
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
@import url("square/_all.css");
@import url("flat/_all.css");
@import url("line/_all.css");
@import url("polaris/polaris.css");
@import url("futurico/futurico.css");
```

Now all I want is When I compile `resources/css/icheck/all.css` file using laravel-mix then all the imported CSS files should be copied in `public/css` folder

Comment: I also encounter this issue, did you already fix yours @Ahmar?